# Document.Fields.Update event in Word 2010 C#

Tags: c#, vsto, word-2010

I have an application level addin for Word 2010 written in C#. I would like to incorporate some document variables. I have no problem updating docvariables with data and calling a Fields.Update. I also have no problem with assigning a method to update all the document variables explicitly.

What I would like to find out is whether there is a Document.Fields.Update event that I can subscribe to in order to update my custom docvariables. E.g. A user clicks a field and selects update or updates the fields for the whole document. Or is there another way that I can bind data to a docvariable field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [repurpose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633%28v=office.12%29.aspx) command

This will be invoked when you do Fields Update, but you need to make sure you are updating the fields manually in the code when you do repurpose.

Ribbon.cs

```
public void TestFieldsUpdate(Office.IRibbonControl control, bool cancelDefault)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Field Updated");
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Fields.Update();
 }
```

IdMso should be valid control identifers. You can find other identifiers [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798).

Ribbon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <commands>        
    <command idMso="FieldsUpdate" onAction="TestFieldsUpdate"/>
  </commands>
</customUI>
```

Comment: Doh! Why didn't I think of that :-) Thanks very much